# How to change View clicking on a butto in UIAlertViewController

Tags: uiview, swift

The UIAlertViewController shows all my text but on clicking doesn't switch to the other View. Here's the code:

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Risposta Esatta", message:"",       preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)


    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Avanti", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: {(UIAlertAction) in
        let secondViewController:SecondViewController = SecondViewController()
        self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
```

Comment: Can you confirm this is being fired?

Answer (score 0):

This just worked for me:

```
@IBAction func choiceBtn(sender: UIButton) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello!", message: "This is Alert sample.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let otherAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
            action in println("pushed OK!")
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: .Cancel) {
            action in self.performSegueWithIdentifier("VC2", sender: self)
        }

        alertController.addAction(otherAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I created a modal presented segue from VC1 to VC2 and also named the identifier VC2.  This code I adapted from the GitHub UIAlertController example here:

https://github.com/eversense/Swift-UIAlertController-Example

There was no segue to another ViewController, so I added that to show you.